# xml2json.js error: Syntax error

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to convert an XML file, after many trials with my AngularJS application, I've simply uploaded on the server the samples.html that I've found at https://github.com/abdmob/x2js .
The result is always the same: on the console I receive a "SCRIPTxxxx: Syntax error xml2json.min.js" and "SCRIPTxxxx: 'X2JS' is undefined". The script is linked normally, like:`<script type="text/javascript" src="/vendor-scripts/xml2json.min.js"></script>` (same issue with xml2json.js) and also this simple code gives the same error: `var x2js = new X2JS();
var xmlText = "<MyRoot><test>Success</test><test2><item>val1</item><item>val2</item></test2></MyRoot>";
var jsonObj = x2js.xml_str2json( xmlText );`. Does anyone know if this is a known issue (I didn't find anything on the net) or if there are other libraries to do this job?